# Primefaces Dynamic Columns with Custom Filters

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, filter, datatable

I need to render a dynamic, filterable table with most columns containing text and a few containing boolean values. Therefore, I basically want to combine these two examples:

[Filter](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml) & [Dynamic Columns](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml)

So I have da p:datatable and within it the following:

```
<p:columns
    value="#{cc.attrs.tableController.tableColumns}"
    var="column"
    headerText="#{column.header}"
    columnIndexVar="colIndex"
    style="#{column.style}"
    sortBy="#{item[column.property]}"
    filterBy="#{item[column.property]}"
    filterMatchMode="contains">

<f:facet name="filter">
    <p:inputText onkeyup="PF('#{cc.attrs.tableController.tableName}').filter()" style="width: 90%" rendered="#{!column.binary}"/>
    <p:selectOneButton onchange="PF('#{cc.attrs.tableController.tableName}').filter()" rendered="#{column.binary}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue=""/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Y" itemValue="true"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="N" itemValue="false"/>
    </p:selectOneButton>
</f:facet>

<h:outputText styleClass="#{item.markedForDeleteStyle}" value="#{item[column.property]}" rendered="#{!column.binary}"/>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{column.binary}"
              class="#{item.archivFlagBoolean ? 'ui-state-active' : 'ui-state-error'}"
              style="border:none!important; background:none!important; color:green!important; box-shadow: none!important;">
    <p:outputPanel layout="inline"
                   styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check"
                   style="margin: auto"
                   rendered="#{item.archivFlagBoolean}"/>
    <p:outputPanel layout="inline"
                   styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"
                   style="margin: auto"
                   rendered="#{!item.archivFlagBoolean}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The problem comes from the two filters in the facet. Using only either one it works fine, but using both results in this error when filtering (yes, that's the entire stacktrace):

```
25.08.2017 15:45:47 com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
SCHWERWIEGEND: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I've tried different versions of this, using includes, c:if, and even swapping p:columns for

```
<c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.tableController.tableColumns}" var="column">
    <p:column [...]>
```

But all of those variants resulted in the same error.

Is there any way to dynamically append columns to a table with several different filters?

---

**Edit**

So, I created a minimalistic example with 3 files:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.logicbig.example</groupId>
<artifactId>data-table-filtering</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fluttercode.datafactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>datafactory</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

A Backing Bean:

```
import org.fluttercode.datafactory.impl.DataFactory;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RecordBean {
private List<Record> recordList = new ArrayList<>();

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    DataFactory dataFactory = new DataFactory();
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        Record employee = new Record();
        employee.setId(i);
        employee.setName(dataFactory.getName());
        employee.setActive(new Random().nextBoolean());
        recordList.add(employee);
    }
}

public List<Record> getRecordList() {
    return recordList;
}

public List<ColumnModel> getColumns() {
    List<ColumnModel> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    columns.add(new ColumnModel("Id", "id"));
    columns.add(new ColumnModel("Name", "name"));
    columns.add(new ColumnModel("Active", "active", true));
    return columns;
}

public class Record {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean active;

    public long getId () {return id;}
    public void setId (long id) {this.id = id;}
    public String getName () {return name;}
    public void setName (String name) {this.name = name;}
    public boolean isActive() {return active;}
    public void setActive(boolean active) {this.active = active;}
}

public class ColumnModel {
    private String header;
    private String property;
    private boolean isBinary;
    public ColumnModel(String header, String property) {
        this(header, property, false);
    }
    public ColumnModel(String header, String property, boolean isBinary) {
        this.header = header;
        this.property = property;
        this.isBinary = isBinary;
    }

    public String getHeader() {return header;}
    public String getProperty() {return property;}
    public boolean isBinary() {return isBinary;}
}
}
```

and an index.xhtml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable var="record" value="#{recordBean.recordList}" widgetVar="recordWidget">
            <p:columns var="column" value="#{recordBean.columns}" headerText="#{column.header}" filterBy="#{record[column.property]}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:inputText onkeyup="PF('recordWidget').filter()" rendered="#{!column.binary}"/>
                    <p:selectOneButton onchange="PF('recordWidget').filter()" rendered="#{column.binary}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue=""/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Y" itemValue="true"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="N" itemValue="false"/>
                    </p:selectOneButton>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{record[column.property]}" />
            </p:columns>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Same thing: either filter on its own works fine, but when using both at the same time I get an error. When building this example, I noticed that Catalina logs a different error than IntelliJ:

```
28-Aug-2017 11:05:43.576 INFORMATION [http-nio-8080-exec-7] com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.UIPanel cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.ValueHolder
 java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.UIPanel cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.ValueHolder
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.populateFilterMetaDataWithoutColumnGroups(FilterFeature.java:402)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.populateFilterMetaData(FilterFeature.java:293)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.decode(FilterFeature.java:93)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processValidators(DataTable.java:847)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:575)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:827)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

28-Aug-2017 11:05:43.577 WARNUNG [http-nio-8080-exec-7] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.UIPanel cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.ValueHolder
 javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.UIPanel cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.ValueHolder
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:273)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.UIPanel cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.ValueHolder
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.populateFilterMetaDataWithoutColumnGroups(FilterFeature.java:402)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.populateFilterMetaData(FilterFeature.java:293)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.decode(FilterFeature.java:93)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processValidators(DataTable.java:847)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:575)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:827)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
... 28 more

28-Aug-2017 11:05:43.577 SCHWERWIEGEND [http-nio-8080-exec-7] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.UIPanel cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.ValueHolder
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.populateFilterMetaDataWithoutColumnGroups(FilterFeature.java:402)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.populateFilterMetaData(FilterFeature.java:293)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.decode(FilterFeature.java:93)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processValidators(DataTable.java:847)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:575)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:827)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does this help?

Comment: You are using them in a composite component. What if you use it directly? And tried the latest PF version?

Comment: When using it directly I get the same error. And I'm using PF 6.1.

Comment: Then please create a [mcve]. See also http://www.stackoverflow/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I added a small example. I hope this helps.

Comment: tried wrapping the two inputs in a fragment/container and then in the facet?

Comment: Yes, I tried that with fragments and panelGroups, both didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

With PrimeFaces 7.0 (and below) this is not possible out of the box. This [forum post](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=59011&p=175508) explains the details and has some useful links to other posts and pull-requests fixing the issues.

Basically you need to use the `filterOptions`-attribute of `<p:columns>` for the binary columns (empty `filterOptions` for other columns) and extend the class [`DataTableRenderer`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java) as explained in the post to avoid `NullPointerException`.

Once [PrimeFaces #4846](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4846) and [PrimeFaces #4847](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4847) are closed, this should be possible without patching the PrimeFace JAR or overriding renderer classes.

**Update:** The PrimeFaces issues from above are fixed/closed now. So empty or `null` `filterOptions`-Attribute should work now.

Comment: The issues are fixed in `master` on github and are targeted for '7.1' milestone which is not yet released. As I'm not an elite user I can't tell in which 7.0.x version the fix went exactly.